# Is there any simple way in SwiftUI to generate a view which shows dates in a month view?

Tags: calendar, swiftui

There are so many complexities to building a calendar month view by myself, I am just trying to find better ways to do it

Comment: This can be customisable as you want -> https://github.com/yodagamaheshan/DateGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy-paste ready

There is fair amount of ready-to-use SwiftUI calendars out there. Here are a few:

- [Option 1](https://gist.github.com/mecid/f8859ea4bdbd02cf5d440d58e936faec)
- [Option 2](https://github.com/RaffiKian/RKCalendar)

And I found these in under a minute of searching.

### 3rd party library

Another approach would be to integrate a 3rd party library in your project. If you search for calendar CocoaPod for example you will stumble on various implementations. But please note that if you go with that approach you should probably also look up how to integrate Storyboards within your SwiftUI application.